# Store database in /assets and access it

Tags: android, database, assets

Hi
 i have very large database so i am not able to store it in...   \data\data\"PACKAGE_NAME"\databases
 
so i want to store database in Assets and access it from there .I do not want to copy database from assets into \data\data\"PACKAGE_NAME"\databases ..
 So any fertile brain there to  plant solution.....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) or its siblings `openOrCreateDatabase` to place a database in a path of your choosing.

Comment: Could u provide me any example to illustrate it?